# Fragment transition support 25.1.0 with Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, kotlin

I was using fragment transitions to animate a view from a recycler view, with the 25.0.1 support lib and the transition was working fine for push and pop the target fragment.

The code I'm using to generate the transaction is:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replaceAddToBackStack(R.id.content, fragment)
    .addSharedElement(fragment, commonViews)
    .commit()
```

Now I'm trying to update to the 25.1.0 version of the support libraries and the pop animation is crashing because the transition is not finding the original views, and is crashing with:

```
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setNameOverridesOptimized(FragmentTransitionCompat21.java:339)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.configureTransitionsOptimized(FragmentTransition.java:232)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:111)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2143)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:822)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:775)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:178)
at App.ui.base.BaseActivity.onBackPressed(BaseActivity.kt:23)
...
```

But if I disable the "optimizations" it works fine.

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .replaceAddToBackStack(R.id.content, fragment)
    .addSharedElement(fragment, commonViews)
    .setAllowOptimization(false)
    .commit()
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
The extensions I'm using to wrap the shared elements:

.replaceAddToBackStack

```
fun<T : Fragment> FragmentTransaction.replaceAddToBackStack(containerView: Int, fragment: T, tag: String? = null) : FragmentTransaction {
  return replace(containerView, fragment, tag).addToBackStack(fragment.toString())
}
```

.addSharedElement

```
fun<T: Fragment, V: View> FragmentTransaction
    .addSharedElement(destination: T?, sharedViews: List<V>?,
                      sharedTransform: TransitionSet? = null,
                      enterTransition: Transition? = null,
                      exitTransition: Transition? = null
                      ) : FragmentTransaction {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    return this
  }
  if (destination == null || sharedViews == null) {
    return this
  }

  val fade = Fade()
  fade.duration = 150
  destination.enterTransition = enterTransition ?: fade
  destination.allowEnterTransitionOverlap = false
  destination.allowReturnTransitionOverlap = false
  destination.exitTransition = exitTransition ?: fade
  destination.sharedElementEnterTransition = sharedTransform ?: DetailsTransition()
  destination.sharedElementReturnTransition = sharedTransform ?: DetailsTransition()

  sharedViews.forEach {
    this.addSharedElement(it, it.transitionName)
  }
  return this
}
```

Comment: I guess there's nothing wrong with your code. It seems like a bug in support library itself. If you take a look on the source code, you can see that NPE happens on this line `inName.equals(inNames.get(j))`. Basically what can be the reason of this NPE is that a shared view in a fragment you try to add has a null as transition name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me since 25.0.1 version. Show your full code or at least commonViews. I think, the problem is in your commonViews.